If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a$, find the minimum value of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ for real $x$, $y$ and $z$.

If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a$, find the minimum value of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ for real $x$, $y$ and $z$ where $a$ is +ve real.

Is it possible to solve it with Cauchy-Schwarz actually ?
('cause we might wanna apply C-S on $(x^\frac{3}{2}, y^\frac{3}{2}, z^\frac{3}{2})$ and $(x^\frac{1}{2}, y^\frac{1}{2}, z^\frac{1}{2})$ which doesn't seems valid as the square roots could give non real complex $a_{i}$s or $b_{i}$s)

What do you think the answer is, and why?

Well it's solution using C-S is given in textbook that's $\frac{a^\frac{3}{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$ maybe C-S can't really be applied here (Jensen or Power Mean Inequality could work)

Do you know Lagrange multiplier technique?

@J.W.Tanner nope

If $x=y=z$, then $x^2=\dfrac a3$, so $x^3+y^3+z^3=3x^3=3\left(\dfrac a3\right)^{3/2}=\dfrac{a^{3/2}}{\sqrt3}$

Please check the allowed range of your $x,y,z$. The minimum of $x^3+y^3+z^3$ for all real $x,y,z$ satisfies $x^2+y^2+z^2 = a$ is $-a^{\frac32}$. If you restrict $x,y,z$ to be non-negative, then the minimum is indeed $\frac{a^{\frac32}}{\sqrt{3}}$ by Jensen (the map $t \mapsto t^{3/2}$ is convex for $t \ge 0$)

If $x=y=0$ and $z=-\sqrt a$, then $x^3+y^3+z^3=-a^{3/2}$

It’s evident that $$-\sqrt{a}\le x,y,z \le \sqrt{a}$$
We have then:
$$x^2(x + \sqrt{a})\ge 0\iff x^3 \ge -\sqrt{a} x^2$$
Same for $y,z$:
$$y^3 \ge -\sqrt{a} y^2 $$
$$z^3 \ge -\sqrt{a} z^2 $$
Make the sum, we deduce then:
$$x^3 +y^3 +z^3 \ge -\sqrt{a}(x^2 + y^2+x^2)=-a^{3/2} $$
The equality occurs if and only if one variable equal to $-\sqrt a$ and these two others equal to $0$.
